# Could not render the home page template in DJango mini project,

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect
from myapp.form import LoginForm
from myapp.models import Login
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    myForm=LoginForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST['name']
        email=request.POST['email']
        password=request.POST['password']
        new_data=Login(Name=name,Email=email,Password=password)
        new_data.save()
        form=LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect("thanks")
    return render(request,'index.html',{'form':myForm})

def thankyou(request):
    return render(request,'thanks.html')
```

and this is my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from myapp import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index),
    path('thanks',views.thankyou),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

i have created a model template view for sample login form, except home page, everything is fine, even superuser also created.

form.py:

```
from dataclasses import field
from pyexpat import model
from django import forms
from myapp.models import Login

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    class Data:
        model=Login,
    field=[
        'Name','Email','Password'
    ]
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from myapp.models import Login
admin.site.register(Login)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Login(models.Model):
    Name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

base.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
    <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
    
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock content %}
    
    
        </body>
        </html>
```

index.html:

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}



<div class="box">
    <center><h3>Create New Account</h3></center>
    <form  class="form" action="" method="POST" colspan="4">
        {% csrf_token %}
        Name : <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" placeholder="name" required>
        <br>
        <br>
        Email : <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="email" autocomplete="off">
        <br>
        <br>
        Password : <input type="password" name="password" required placeholder="enter new password">
        <br>
    
        <input type="submit" name="signup" value="Create">
       
    </form>
    <label id="in"><a href="login.html">Already Have Account?</a></label>
    <a href="login.html">
        <button>Login</button>
      </a>

</div>
<div>

</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

thanks.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

 {% block content %}
 
 <h1>Thankyou</h1>
 {% endblock content %}
```

so i have creating a login page as i mentioned above, server is running except home page, superuser, admin page also working without issues.migrations done.

Comment: I see you have a typo in your index.html: </fomr> should be </form>.

Comment: And also in your index view you have two return statements one after one, it doesn't work that way.

Comment: ok bro, i will post my recent files from the project, please verify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect
from myapp.form import LoginForm
from myapp.models import Login
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    myForm=LoginForm()
    if request.method=="POST":
        name=request.POST['name']
        password=request.POST['password']
        new_data=Login(Name=name,Password=password)
        new_data.save()
        form=LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect("thanks")
     return render(request,'index.html',{'form':myForm}) #your indentation is misplaced

def thankyou(request):
    return render(request,'thanks.html')
```

Comment: bro thank you i have edited that but still facing error in terminal. and in webpage.
in web:
OperationalError at /
table myapp_login has no column named Email

Comment: in terminal when i try to make migrations:
Was login.password renamed to login.Email (a CharField)? [y/N] n
Was login.password renamed to login.Password (a CharField)? [y/N] n
It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'Email' to login without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.
Select an option:

Comment: that means you are not defined such column i.e. field in your database. So accessing field that are not defined give us such errors. have a look at your models and view.py file where you have accessed it.

Comment: i have edited my files above, can you check it bro?

Comment: delete your sqlite database and then try running migrate and makemigrations command. must work fine!

Comment: bro dbsqlite couldnot deleted, it says resource busy or blocked

Comment: C:\Users\rames\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts\myproject>python manage.py makemigrations
Was login.password renamed to login.Email (a CharField)? [y/N] n
Was login.password renamed to login.Password (a CharField)? [y/N] n
It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'Email' to login without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.

Comment: Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.
Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value as valid Python.
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so it is possible to provide e.g. timezone.now as a value.
Type 'exit' to exit this prompt

Comment: these errosrs arise bro. and couldnot delete dbsqlite

Comment: add default value in model.py file. simple!

Comment: bro how to add default value.

Comment: yourfieldname=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) like this

Comment: Thankyou bro issues resolved

Answer (score 0):

**Your view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect
from myapp.form import LoginForm
from myapp.models import Login
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    myForm=LoginForm()
    if request.method=="POST":
        name=request.POST['name']
        password=request.POST['password']
        new_data=Login(Name=name,Password=password)
        new_data.save()
        form=LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect("thanks")
    return render(request,'index.html',{'form':myForm})

def thankyou(request):
    return render(request,'thanks.html')
```

**My change**
In your index function

```
from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect
    from myapp.form import LoginForm
    from myapp.models import Login
    # Create your views here.
    def index(request):
        myForm=LoginForm()
        if request.method=="POST":
            name=request.POST['name']
            password=request.POST['password']
            new_data=Login(Name=name,Password=password)
            new_data.save()
            form=LoginForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                return HttpResponseRedirect("thanks")
        return render(request,'index.html',{'form':myForm})
```

For Example
My Django app name is blog

```
return render(request,'blog/index.html',{'form':myForm})
```

In your thankyou function

```
return render(request,'your app name/thanks.html')
```

**Changes in setiing.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

**My CRUD project's views.py**

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Username Or Password is inccorect')
```

Comment: tried bro still error comes, for 
index.html :ValueError at /
The view myapp.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

for thanks.html:
TemplateDoesNotExist at /thanks

Comment: you can write message at the place of HttpResponse using message freamwork

Comment: sorry i can't understand what you are saying